# Boost python typedef

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I am trying to expose the C++ class with name aliasing to python using boost python.

```
struct Foo
{
  void hi() const { std::cout << "hi" << std::endl; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Example)
{
  typedef Foo Bar;

  class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def("hi", &Foo::hi)
  ;

  class_<Bar>("Bar")
    .def("hi", &Bar::hi)
  ;
}
```

The code works as expected except the annoying RuntimeWarning.

```
RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for Foo already registered; second conversion method ignore
```

Adding `Bar = Foo` in python also works. But I need to keep the definitions in the same module. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the "C++ equivalent to the Python `Bar = Foo`" approach that Ulrich mentions.

You can use [`boost::python::scope`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components/boost_python_scope_hpp.html) to get access to the current module and its attributes.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::python;

struct Foo
{
    void hi() const { std::cout << "hi" << std::endl; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Example)
{
    bp::class_<Foo>("Foo")
        .def("hi", &Foo::hi)
        ;

    bp::scope().attr("Bar") = bp::scope().attr("Foo");
}
```

Comment: Wow. That's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since `typedef` only introduces an alias, your code just registers the same class under different names.

Suggestions:

- Why would you want that anyway? Just register it once under its real name. As you mentioned, creating an alias in Python (again, why?) is easy.
- If you just declared a baseclass and derived both `Foo` and `Bar` from it, you would have different types and the warning would vanish, too.
- You could probably also write a C++ equivalent to the Python `Bar = Foo`, i.e. a simple assignment of an object to a name in the module namespace.

Given the feedback below that it's required to support legacy code, here's what I would do:

```
// same as above
struct Foo { ... };

// For legacy reasons, it is mandatory that Foo is exported
// under two names. In order to introduce new C++ types, we
// just derive from the original Foo. The approach using a
// typedef doesn't work because it only creates an alias but
// not an existing type.
struct FooType: Foo {};
struct BarType: Foo {};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Example)
{
  class_<FooType>("Foo")
    .def("hi", &FooType::hi)
  ;
  class_<BarType>("Bar")
    .def("hi", &BarType::hi)
  ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The dilemma comes from the fact that I couldn't change much on the legacy C++ class definitions. Also, I am creating a python module for user who wants everything is there with one single module load. However, I couldn't understand your last point. The C++ equivalent to the aliasing in Python should be `typedef` or `using`. They work well in pure C++. But I still need `Bar` to be defined in the Example module.

Comment: Yes and no. Using a `typedef` or `using`, you create an alias. However, both the original name and the alias refer to the same type. What you want is a different type, even though it should behave like alike. In other words, you want equality but not identity. I'll try to illustrate this part with example code.

Comment: What I need was actually aliasing, i.e., refer to the same type. Your technique also works, but I am still expecting some other tricks to achieve it via boost with minimal coding complexity.